# USB network for IOS

Tags: ios, usb, mux

There are a number of apps coming out at the moment, that solve the problem of USB networking to a MAC/PC on IOS. Up until now, it was only possible to set up a USB network if the IOS device was jailbroken - however, that's all changed recently.

The apps seem to be using tunneling over USB mux. There's a couple of examples here -

- https://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Usbmux
- https://code.google.com/p/iphonetunnel-usbmuxconnectbyport/

USB mux seems to use TCP connection. I'm wondering whether it is feasible for a UDP connection to be used instead of TCP? I'm guessing this would require some kind of app on the PC/MAC to open a connection when the USB cable is plugged in?

Anyone know any information about this new phenomenon?